# Adding Dynamic Hashmap Keys

Tags: java

I would like to ask if I'm able to add dynamic hashmap keys in java?

For Example

```
...
String name = reader.next();
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(name, 1);
```

Using this method, how can I add multiple data without doing this:

```
...
...
map.put("JACK", 1);
map.put("JOHN", 2);
map.put("JACKER", 3);
```

And also, how can I loop through my hashmap to print out all the keys in hashmap?

Comment: Time to learn about [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()).

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple elements use a loop, like a for loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
int i = 1;
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    map.put(s, i++);
}
printMap(map);
```

To print a `HashMap` we use `iterator`.

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you add an int in a string parameter?

Comment: @GODDESS I edited the answer, forgot to change. It will work now.